# Mouseover to display/hide force layout links

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Being new to d3 (and javascript) I've been trying to combine a force layout with a background image. Goal is to create a node for every person in the image, and display the social connections of this person to all others in the images using svg links. I've used a subset of a *Les Miserables* force layout to test this.
I've created a few 'fixed' positions in the force layout (e. Valjean, Cosette, Javert, Eponine).

[See this image example of Les Miserables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiica.jpg)

Key problem is the vast quantity of interconnections, which looks impressive but makes it useless to present.
I'd like to add a mouseover function that displays only the links of the person/node at the mouse position.

I've looked at one alternative mechanism: Mike Bostock's [airport force layout](https://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/airports.html) has this mouseover function but is far to complex for me, unfortunately, because I do not need all these geo scripts.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #9cf;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
* {font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#fff;}
</style>
<svg width="1400" height="900" style="background:url('miserables_op.jpg');background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var graph = {
 nodes:[
    {"id": "Myriel", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Napoleon", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1},
    {"id": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Geborand", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Champtercier", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Cravatte", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Count", "group": 1},
    {"id": "OldMan", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Labarre", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Valjean", "fx":1300, "fy":570, "group": 2},
    {"id": "Marguerite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.deR", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Isabeau", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Gervais", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Tholomyes", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Listolier", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fameuil", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Blacheville", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Favourite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Dahlia", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Zephine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fantine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Cosette", "fx":1245, "fy":625, "group": 5},
    {"id": "Javert", "fx":110, "fy":450,"group": 4},
    {"id": "Fauchelevent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Bamatabois", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Perpetue", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Simplice", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Scaufflaire", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Woman1", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Judge", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Champmathieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Brevet", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Chenildieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Cochepaille", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Pontmercy", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Boulatruelle", "group": 6},
    {"id": "Eponine", "fx":535, "fy":535, "group": 4},
    {"id": "Anzelma", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Woman2", "group": 5},
    {"id": "MotherInnocent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Gribier", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Jondrette", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Mme.Burgon", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Gavroche", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Magnon", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mme.Pontmercy", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Vaubois", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Lt.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Marius", "group": 8}
 ],
  links: [
    {"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Myriel", "value": 10},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 6},
    {"source": "CountessdeLo", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Geborand", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Champtercier", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cravatte", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Count", "target": "Myriel", "value": 2},
    {"source": "OldMan", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Labarre", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mme.Magloire", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Myriel", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Marguerite", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.deR", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Isabeau", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gervais", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Listolier", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Favourite", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Zephine", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Marguerite", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Valjean", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 13},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 12},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Valjean", "value": 31},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Valjean", "value": 17},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Fantine", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 8},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Perpetue", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Perpetue", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Scaufflaire", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Chenildieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Pontmercy", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Boulatruelle", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Eponine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 3},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gribier", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Burgon", "target": "Jondrette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Mme.Burgon", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Vaubois", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 12},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Lt.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Cosette", "value": 21},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Valjean", "value": 19},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Eponine", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 4}
  ]
};
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(400))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 1.8));

var link = svg.append("g") //essential to define the links
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node") //essential to define the nodes
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
 .attr("class", "node")
    .call(d3.drag() //enables the dragging function (see further down)
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));
       
node.append("circle") 
  .attr("r", 8)
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });

node.append("text") 
  .attr("dx", -5)
 .attr("dy", -15) 
    .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
 
simulation 
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", tick);

simulation.force("link") 
      .links(graph.links);

function ticked() { 
 node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
   }

function tick() {  //creates layout, essential
      link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
      node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    };

function dragstarted(d,i) {
        simulation.stop()
}

function dragged(d, i) { 
        d.x += d3.event.dx;
        d.y += d3.event.dy;
        tick();
}
function dragended(d, i) {l
        d.fixed = true;
  simulation.alphaTarget(0).restart();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouse over example you point to is also complicated by the voronoi tesselation on top of the geographic features. But if you only want to

> add a mouseover function that displays only the links of the
>   person/node at the mouse position.

Then your solution is relatively easy. You will need to add event listeners for `mouseover` and `mouseout` events on each node:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node") //essential to define the nodes
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on('mouseover',mouseover)
    .on('mouseout',mouseout)
    .call(d3.drag() //enables the dragging function (see further down)
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));
```

Then create the functions for each:

```
function mouseover(d) {
  link.filter(function(e) {  return e.target.id == d.id || e.source.id == d.id; })
    .style('opacity',1)
    .style('stroke','black')
}

function mouseout(d) {
  link.style('stroke', "#9cf")
      .style('stroke-opacity', 0.6);
}
```

The mouseon function has a filter to filter nodes so that only those nodes that have a source or target equal to the currently mouseovered node are modified - the mouseout function doesn't need this, so it is indiscriminate.

All together, those modifications give you:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #9cf;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

highlight {
  stroke: black !important;
  stroke-width: 10px;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
* {font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#fff;}
</style>
<svg width="1400" height="900" style="background:url('miserables_op.jpg');background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var graph = {
 nodes:[
    {"id": "Myriel", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Napoleon", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1},
    {"id": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Geborand", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Champtercier", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Cravatte", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Count", "group": 1},
    {"id": "OldMan", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Labarre", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Valjean", "fx":1300, "fy":570, "group": 2},
    {"id": "Marguerite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.deR", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Isabeau", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Gervais", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Tholomyes", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Listolier", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fameuil", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Blacheville", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Favourite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Dahlia", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Zephine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fantine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Cosette", "fx":1245, "fy":625, "group": 5},
    {"id": "Javert", "fx":110, "fy":450,"group": 4},
    {"id": "Fauchelevent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Bamatabois", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Perpetue", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Simplice", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Scaufflaire", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Woman1", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Judge", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Champmathieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Brevet", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Chenildieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Cochepaille", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Pontmercy", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Boulatruelle", "group": 6},
    {"id": "Eponine", "fx":535, "fy":535, "group": 4},
    {"id": "Anzelma", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Woman2", "group": 5},
    {"id": "MotherInnocent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Gribier", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Jondrette", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Mme.Burgon", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Gavroche", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Magnon", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mme.Pontmercy", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Vaubois", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Lt.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Marius", "group": 8}
 ],
  links: [
    {"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Myriel", "value": 10},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 6},
    {"source": "CountessdeLo", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Geborand", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Champtercier", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cravatte", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Count", "target": "Myriel", "value": 2},
    {"source": "OldMan", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Labarre", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mme.Magloire", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Myriel", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Marguerite", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.deR", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Isabeau", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gervais", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Listolier", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Favourite", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Zephine", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Marguerite", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Valjean", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 13},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 12},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Valjean", "value": 31},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Valjean", "value": 17},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Fantine", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 8},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Perpetue", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Perpetue", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Scaufflaire", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Chenildieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Pontmercy", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Boulatruelle", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Eponine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 3},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gribier", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Burgon", "target": "Jondrette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Mme.Burgon", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Vaubois", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 12},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Lt.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Cosette", "value": 21},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Valjean", "value": 19},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Eponine", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 4}
  ]
};
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(400))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 1.8));

var link = svg.append("g") //essential to define the links
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node") //essential to define the nodes
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
 .attr("class", "node")
    .on('mouseover',mouseover)
    .on('mouseout',mouseout)
    .call(d3.drag() //enables the dragging function (see further down)
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));
       
node.append("circle") 
  .attr("r", 8)
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });

node.append("text") 
  .attr("dx", -5)
 .attr("dy", -15) 
    .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
 
simulation 
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", tick);

simulation.force("link") 
      .links(graph.links);

function ticked() { 
 node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
   }

function tick() {  //creates layout, essential
      link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
      node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    };

function dragstarted(d,i) {
        simulation.stop()
}

function dragged(d, i) { 
        d.x += d3.event.dx;
        d.y += d3.event.dy;
        tick();
}
function dragended(d, i) {l
        d.fixed = true;
  simulation.alphaTarget(0).restart();
}

function mouseover(d) {
  link.filter(function(e) {  return e.target.id == d.id || e.source.id == d.id; })
    .style('opacity',1)
    .style('stroke','black')
}

function mouseout(d) {
  link.style('stroke', "#9cf")
      .style('stroke-opacity', 0.6);
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much Andrew! The highlighted links are even better than I'd hoped for. This combination of force layout, background image, and mouseover will allow anyone to combine large family or school pictures with the names of the persons and how they relate to each other. If I may expand on my question: Is there an option to use the links to create (e.g. Ajaxed) tooltip/window giving more details on how these persons relate to each other?